# Do odd PNG resolutions have an impact on the format's efficiency?

Tags: png, resolution

I'm currently optimizing a website that is using some PNGs with odd sizes like 263x263. Seeing that JPG has some limitations when dealing with resolutions that require MCU-blocks (minimum coded unit) with a size smaller than 1, I was wondering whether PNG suffers from any limitations of such sort regarding unorthodox resolutions that aren't a multiple of at least 2, such as lower compression or compatibility with devices and browsers.

Comment: Odd sizes are OK in PNG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the PNG format does not care at all whether width and height sizes are odd numbers. Each line has its own "filter", and the concatenation is compressed as a single stream.  There's no reason to try to make width or height even or "nice" numbers.

Comment: The line filtering does not come into play at all. The bulk compression is on a linear bytestream only. The line filters have an effect on the total compression, but they do not care about even or odd widths or heights either.